# Making a Stacked Bar Graph for character occurence

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble plotting a stacked bar graph for three columns where I wanted to try to have two sets of all the variations of `df$S` on the x axis (one for `I15` and `I19`). Then, I want to fill with the frequency of each character in their respective columns. So essentially, three columns of "NONE", "SILENT", and "MISSENSE" for `I15` and three columns for `I19` and then fill them with how many times each character appears, if that makes sense. But whenever I try to plot it comes up empty with only the y and x axis labeled. I tried using a code Ive used in the past for stacked box graphs but no luck.

```
df %>%
+   pivot_longer(-S) %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = S, y = value, fill = c(I15, I19))


              S  I15  I19
    1      NONE  1/1 <NA>
    2      NONE  0/1  1/0
    3      NONE  1/1  1/1
    4      NONE  0/1  0/1
    5      NONE  0/0 <NA>
    6      NONE  1/1  1/1
    7      NONE  1/1  1/1
    8      NONE  0/1  1/0
    9      NONE  0/1  1/0
    10     NONE  1/1  1/1
    11     NONE  0/1  0/1
    12     NONE  1/1  1/1
    13     NONE  0/1  1/0
    14     NONE  1/1  1/1
    15 MISSENSE  0/1  0/1
    16 MISSENSE  0/1  0/1
    17     NONE <NA> <NA>
    18     NONE  0/1  1/0
    19     NONE  1/1  1/1
    20     NONE  1/1  1/1
    21     NONE  1/1  1/1
    22     NONE  1/1  1/1
    23     NONE  1/1  1/1
    24     NONE <NA> <NA>
    25     NONE <NA> <NA>
    26     NONE <NA> <NA>
    27     NONE  0/1  1/1
    28     NONE  0/1  1/1
    29     NONE  0/1  1/1
    30     NONE  1/1  1/1
    31   SILENT  1/1 <NA>
    32     NONE  1/1  1/1
    33   SILENT  1/1  1/1
    34     NONE  0/1  0/1
    35     NONE  0/1  0/1
    36     NONE  0/1  1/0
    37 MISSENSE  0/1  1/0
    38     NONE  0/1  1/0
    39   SILENT  0/1  0/0
    40     NONE  1/1  1/1
    41     NONE  0/1  1/0
    42     NONE  1/1  1/0
    43     NONE  0/1  1/0
    44     NONE  0/1  1/0
    45     NONE  0/1  0/1
    46     NONE  0/1  0/1
    47     NONE  0/1  0/1
    48     NONE  0/1  0/1
    49     NONE <NA>  0/0
    50   SILENT  0/1  0/1
```

Comment: You forgot to provide `geom_bar(stat="count",position="dodge")`. And if the data below the code is `f`, the variable given to `fill` should be only `name`.

Comment: df %>%
+   pivot_longer(-S) %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = S, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_bar(stat="count",position="dodge")
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.     If I run this I get this kind of error

Comment: That's true, I'm sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? Count by group (S, name, value) and use facets for the names, to make the x-axis less crowded.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-S) %>% 
  count(S, name, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(S, n)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = value)) + 
  facet_grid(name ~ .)
```

Result:

[image]